# How do I Improve CollectionView Performance

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a landing page that has this layout:

[image: layout]

When you click on one of the section buttons, the ObservableCollection in the ViewModel is set to another list as so:

```
private async void processtableOfContentsListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
     var tocItem = e?.Item as TableOfContentsItem;
     if (viewModel.SelectedTableOfContentsItem == tocItem)
     {
         return;
     }
    viewModel.CurrentSectionItems = tocItem.SectionItems;
    viewModel.SelectedTableOfContentsItem = tocItem;
 }
```

This is simplified as there's other operations going on.

My problem is that the CollectionView is taking too long to change sections. There's a noticeable delay when trying to load up the new items. To be fair, the DataTemplate's for the items are a little complex. I've simplified them as much as possible, but you can still notice a delay in trying to draw them.

I'd like to speed this change up as much as possible, but its starting to look like I may need to just deal with the delay itself instead of freezing. It would be nice to have a loading indication in between changing sections. Like an ActivityIndicator. But I can't seem to find how to make UI changes in the beginning of the EventHandler for the buttons. Even if I clear the ObservableCollection in the beginning of the event handler, it still will wait until the method finishes before showing any UI changes.

I've checked and the event handler is running on the main UI thread. I've even tried running the rest of the code on a background thread after changing the section to see if it would before continuing the method, but no luck:

```
 private async void processtableOfContentsListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (MainThread.IsMainThread) //is true
     {   
     }

     var tocItem = e?.Item as TableOfContentsItem;

     await Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => {
             viewModel.SelectedTableOfContentsItem = tocItem;
             viewModel.CurrentSectionItems = tocItem.SectionItems;
         });
     });
        
     Task.Run(() => DoWork(sender, e));

 }
```

My question is two parted.

Does anyone have an idea how to speed up the redrawing of the CollectionView?

If not, how do I set off the UI change to clear the CollectionView in the beginning of the event handler so I can add a loading indicator?

Comment: roughly how many rows are in each section - a few or dozens or hundreds?  Is the data static or dynamic?  Have you isolated the delay so that you're sure it is the CollectionView and not some other operation(s) that are slow?  Is the data for all the sections in memory, or are you loading from a db or external resource?

Comment: The number of rows can be variable but on average 20. The data is static and is saved in memory. I am loading all the data from the database when the page first loads. I have narrowed it down to specifically the CollectionView as there's no loading of new data when switching sections.

Comment: I'd try creating 5 collectionviews and just toggling their visibility to see if that gets you the result you want

Comment: A loading indicator is always more user friendly than a freeze, but you can also try Jason's way when there are not too many rows. And another way to test is to just bind one property for each item to make the CollectionView simple, if that speed up the rendering, probably try something on the complexity of the CollectionView then.

Comment: `CollectionView` has lots of performance issues, as opposed to the marketing it had. Regarding question 1, first thing is to set `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"` if your items have the same height. Then to improve your template we would need to see the code / layout to detect potential issues. For instance: abusing `Auto` on Grids leads to performance issues

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm experiencing the exact problem. I have a rather simple data template but janks and jitters badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making separate collection views for each section. There is a delay in initializing the list when you first switch to it, but switching between sections has become instant.